# ReadyAimFire and the application class

Tags: mobile, android, push

I am currently experimenting with salesforce mobile push and being no Android developer I am encountering some trouble by simply following the guide.  When I create my Application class the readyAimFire() methid is not being recognized as a symbol also when I Call my aplicattionclass in the manifest it is not being recognized as a class, I am wondering if anyone has had this problem and how to solve it.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is question off topic but I'll ask just to try to clarify. What "guide" are you trying to follow? A quick google search leads me to believe it might be the [Journey Builder for Apps Android SDK](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/)

Comment: Yes Sir that is exactly it, is the documentation I received from my rep, here is a link,  http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html

Comment: This item is on-topic for the Salesforce Marketing Cloud Android Mobile Push SDK.  It should _not_ be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this learning app](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid).  In particular, pay attention to the dependencies in the [app/build.gradle](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L44) file and the `<application>` tag in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L17) file.

Without any data other than is provided in your question it sounds like you've missed the Gradle dependencies and you must create a Class that extends Android Application.  You tell Android to call this class by adding `android:name="{name of your application class, just like you use for your activity definitions}"`

All of the steps in the [SDK IMPLEMENTATION - GOOGLE](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/implement-sdk-google.html) Documentation must be followed.